# Keeping mealworms alive

Tags: feeding, leopard-geckos

We have adopted a "mack snow" leopard gecko this weekend, from the local exotic pet store. She's called Rosie (my 7yo son chose her name). She is being fed on mealworms & crickets, but the crickets will come later... for now, we have a small carton of mealworms. What tools/techniques can I use to ensure the longevity of the mealworms, such that I'm not discarding a significant portion week on week? I have put some thin slices of carrot into the boxed mealworms on stand-by. Can I do the same with the mealworms in her feed bowl? I appreciate the added benefit of "gut-loading" by feeding the mealworms on stand-by.

Edit: She's now called Snowy.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! To keep your new friend as healthy as possible, please have a look at these questions: [What types of food and vitamins are appropriate for a leopard gecko?](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1751/12501), and especially [Baby leopard gecko won't eat!](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/16925/12501). There is a lot more useful information in other [question about leopard geckos](https://pets.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20%5bleopard-geckos%5d)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Short term storage

According to [mom.com](https://animals.mom.com/how-to-store-mealworms-8532112.html), meal worms prefer dry food, oatmeal, wheat bran, chicken mash or cornmeal. They suggest to use a 2- to 5-gallons container (7.5 to 19 litres) made of plastic with a sealing lid. Add about an inch of dry food to it. Then place a chunk of raw potato, apple, carrot or banana peel to it. Make sure to change the humid food every 1 - 2 days to prevent mold.

Pour in the worms, seal the lid and poke some small holes in to the lid, small enough to not let any worms get trough. Then place the container in a dark place at temperatures below 80 degrees Fahrenheit (about 26.7 °C *) for short-term storage.

* Other pages recommend ([thegutload.com](https://thegutload.com/how-to-store-mealworms/)) 65 - 70 °F (18.3 - 21.1 °C)

## Long term storage

Also according to [mom.com](https://animals.mom.com/how-to-store-mealworms-8532112.html), use grain instead of oatmeal or similar and don't provide any wet food. Then put it into the fridge. There's no temperature range specified on that page, but [thegutload.com](https://thegutload.com/how-to-store-mealworms/) recommends 40 - 50 °F (4.4 - 10 °C).

[The birdhouse chick](https://www.thebirdhousechick.com/blogs/resources/92964867-dealing-with-live-mealworms) recommends to pour in the grains, then the worms, then some sliced apple (remove seeds and housing before) and keep the container in a cool place (but outside of the fridge) for 24 hours. Then remove the wet food and proceed to put the container in the fridge. Otherwise, they're missing nutrients which your gecko will miss later.

## Outcome

According to [thegutload.com](https://thegutload.com/how-to-store-mealworms/) the methods explained above can prolong the larvae stage from about 10 - 11 weeks to 16 - 22 weeks. That's 50 to 100 % more time to use them.

## Additional Notes

Always keep the container as dry as possible. Mealworms don't like humidity that much.

For the worms you've already put into the bowl of your gecko, just add some oatmeal for them to feed on. Although you should never put too many mealworms in the bowl at once. Geckos may eat too much, which can lead to problems (see [The bearded dragon](http://www.thebeardeddragon.org/leopard-gecko/leopard-gecko-diet.php))

Comment: Thanks Tim. We're running at much smaller quantities, but some of what you've said still applies.

Comment: You're welcome. Unfortunately, none of the sites linked in the answer contained any info on how many mealworms would be stored using these techniques. Some were using smaller plastic containers like those from the super markets containing [freshly cut water melon pieces](https://images.heb.com/is/image/HEBGrocery/001205788) or smoothies. Just make sure to clean them thoroughly before using them for storage and reduce the amount of food accordingly.