# Leopard gecko with stuck debris in her butt

Tags: health, leopard-geckos, defecation

So my daughter's leopard gecko has stuck junk in her trunk. She has been pooping fine, but there is a piece of hard poo that won't come out. I don't think it is impaction. My daughter has been trying to remove it carefully with tweezers and a wet cotton swab, but it is as hard as a rock. The droppings are also very stuck inside and are hard to remove or even pull out.

Things used in her enclosure:

- Coconut fiber
- 10 gallon tank
- Fake plants
- Plastic water bowl
- Wood branch
- Plastic realistic hide

Should I stop using any of these items? Does this happen often? Do I need medical help or can I do it myself? What is the cause? She eats only mealworms, some crickets, and they are dusted with calcium and vitamins. Otherwise, she is in great health. Please help, I am worried! Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Pets! A picture would help a lot. Does it look like [clogged femoral pores](https://aminoapps.com/c/reptiles/page/item/unclogging-femoral-pores/N4Qq_QlbCWI4X4GL07P0327Qo5WMM50VbVPiK) or is it actual poo? What's the humidity in the enclosure? Please [edit] your question and provide more information. Mealworms are not very nutritious and shouldn't make up the majority of the diet, as explained in [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/1751/12501) and [this question](https://pets.stackexchange.com/q/16925/12501).